# store PDF file in DB as byte

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am using Asp.Net MVC. in my project while uploading PDF file we convert the PDF   file into byte then store it in DB. but i got  the following exception.

" String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated."

Can any one solve this issue.I got the exception righ here

context.SubmitChanges();

Thanks:
Suresh

Comment: Please provide the details about the database, which dbms you are using and what is the data type and length of the column in which you are storing the file.

Comment: that looks like a SQL server error message

Answer (score 1):

Just change the size of your field, try varbinary(MAX).

Comment: Does this answer it for you? Babar is correct that the database field used to store the file as a byte array is too small, sql server is throwing the 'binary data would be truncated' exception on insert. You should increase the field size to something that you know can accommodate the data you are trying to put in or just set it to MAX.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because the code attempted to insert more data/bytes in your database column than its defined size.